# Ant javac task not compiling. Its 'srcdir' parameter not behaving as documented. Is this a bug?

Tags: java, build, ant, compilation, javac

I have written the Ant script pasted below.  It uses the `javac` task.  The Apache documentation states that `scrdir` parameter is used to point to the source (.java) files.  But it also explains that the `javac` task can use patternsets.

I believe there may be a bug in the `javac` task or at least, perhaps a poor implementation of the `javac` Ant task.

In my code, the compile target fails because the source files cannot be found.  Can anyone please explain why?

**Background:**

Directory structure of my project is as follows:

[image]

My ant scripts are in the ant directory.

Source files are inside wm-adapter/src

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="wm-adapter" default="dev" basedir=".">


<property file="Build.properties"/>
<property name="build.compiler" value="javac1.5"/>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
    
    <!-- Define required FileSets and PatternSets... -->
    <patternset id="patternset.wm.adapter.sources">
        <include name="${source.dir}/*.java"/>
        <exclude name=""/>
    </patternset>
    
    <fileset id="fileset.wm.adapter.sources" dir="${proj.dir}">
        <patternset refid="patternset.wm.adapter.sources"/>
    </fileset>
    
    <!-- Compile... -->
    <javac      srcdir="${basedir}"
                destdir="${classes.dir}"
                classpath="${compile.classpath}"
                debug="${javac.debug}"
                verbose="true"
                fork="true"
                source="1.5"
                target="1.5">
                
        
        <patternset refid="patternset.wm.adapter.sources"/>
        
    </javac>
    <echo message="     Compilation completed successfully!"/>
</target>
```

Here is a snippet from the properties file:

```
# DEFINE DIRECTORY STRUCTURE...
proj.dir=../wm-adapter
source.dir=${proj.dir}/src
build.dir=${proj.dir}/build
classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
dist.dir=${proj.dir}/dist
lib.dir=../lib
docs.dir=${proj.dir}/documentation
resources.dir=${proj.dir}/www
config.dir=${proj.dir}/config


# DECLARE ANY OTHER WORKING DIRECTORIES...
tmp.jar.dir=C:\\Temp
tmp.app.dir=${tmp.jar.dir}/FATCA_WM_Adapter


# Name the jar file...
jar.file=FATCA_WM_Adapter.jar


# IMPORT EXTERNAL JARS INTO OUR CLASSPATH...
compile.classpath=${g11nutils.jar};${javax.ejb_3.0.jar};${middleware_UTILS.jar};${wmbrokerclient.jar};${classes.dir}
compile.classpath=${classes.dir};${lib.dir}
```

basedir has been defined as '.'

I know how to make it work: The target will compile if:

1. I make changes to the patternset as shown below:

   ```
   <patternset id="patternset.wm.adapter.sources">
       <include name="src/*.java"/>
       <exclude name=""/>
   </patternset>
   ```
2. Within the javac task I ammend `srcdir` to:

`srcdir="${proj.dir}"`

But this is a fix!  Why do my original settings not work?

Comment: Why not just set `srcdir` parameter to your src directory? Did you try `srcdir="../wm-adapter/src"`

Answer (score 0):

basedir here is equal to your 'ant' subdir, which is probably why it doesn't work. Perhaps you want `<project basedir="..">` at the top.

Comment: @ rzwitserloot   Thank you. I was aware of that.  However, if you look, at my patternset:  <include name="${source.dir}/*.java"/>   should successfully navigate ant to the source folder.  ${source.dir}/*.java translates to 'wm-adapter/src' from the ant directory, does it not?  This is why I am confused.  This should work but it doesn't and I think it is a bug.